# MongoDB C# - Update to clear a list

Tags: c#, mongodb

If I have an object with a list:

```
List<string> myList { get; set; }
```

How can I do a mongodb update to do the equivalent of:

```
myList.Clear();
```

Can it be done with an update / pullall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.update({}, { $set : {'myArray': [] }} , {multi:true} )`

or

`db.collection.update({}, { $pull : { 'myArray': {} }}, {multi:true} )`

will both do the job but `$set` is the proper way of doing this since this operation doesn't do any calculations in the array like `$pull` does. This is all relevant if you must hold on to the empty array.